# Форма не передаёт данные в php скрипт

Tags: php, html, email, str-replace

есть форма следующего вида:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <form method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Message: </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="sended" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

есть скрипт на php:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['sended'])) {
        died("Йуху");
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $masteremail="leshaber24@yandex.ru";
    $html = file_get_contents("./email-inlined.html");
// Массивы с заменой
    $search = array("#name#", "#email#", "#message#");
    $replace = array($name, $email, $message);
    $email_message = str_replace($search, $replace, $html); 
// create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$masteremail."\r\n".
    'Reply-To:'.$masteremail."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";   
    mail($masteremail, "письмо из Сакуры", $html, $headers);  
    ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <h1>Спасибо за обращение, всё будет хорошо!</h1>
```

и соотвественно файлик, который отправляется получателю:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Письмо с сайта</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>Привет, это письмо от <span>#name#</span></p>
        <p>email на который надо ответить <span>#email#</span></p>
        <p>само сообщение:<br><span>#message#</span></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

так вот когда приходит письмо мне на почту, в нём не происходит замены переменных между знаком # на те, которые были введены в форму на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить к полям id, что бы было так:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email">
```

Comment: сделал, всё равно не подставляет, по полю name забираются же в php данные или нет?

Comment: по name не всегда срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Исправить аргумент в функции отправки таким образом:

```
mail($mastermail, "письмо из Сакуры", $email_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="sended">
```

У меня так вот работает отлично. Могу кинуть форму отправки через sockets работает быстрее чем через mail, но сейчас так писать уже не модно. Через ajax и onclick без перезагрузки страницы было бы современнее. и для отправки почты лучше python имхо

Comment: Спасибо, уже поправил, выше отметил, что было не так...